# Why does rails terminal still await input after I copy paste in some code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, console

When copy pasting in some code like:

```
params = { :user => { :email =>“yencn02@yahoo.com"} }
```

The console still is awaiting input, and I have to CTRL+C to escape from it.
The console then says:

```
>> params
=> nil
```

But it works at my colleague's. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a UTF-8 character in there which is messing things up.
Namely the `“` character. Replace it with the standard `"` character and it should work.